# Hearthstone Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

How I can install Hearthstone in a Vivid Vervet Ubuntu (15.04).
I'm totally new using Linux and simply I can't install this, I need help, because when I open the battlenet launcher with Playonlinux, the game, Hearthstone starts with a permanently black screen.
My processor is intel and my video card is NVIDIA Geforce.

Thank you all.

Comment: Another thing, the first time I opened Hearthstone in ubuntu, I changed the quality and put on ''High''. After that Hearthstone only has a black screen opening it from battlenet.

Answer (score 13):

I've installed **Hearthstone** 2 days ago and I have used [Play on linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/es/). It makes the installation very easy and automatic.

Steps:

1. Install PlayOnLinux

   - You can install it using Ubuntu Software Center [click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/playonlinux)
   - Or download it from their home page [Download PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)
2. Once you have PlayOnLinux installed just look for Hearthstone and follow installation steps:

Open PLayOnlinux and click install:
[image]

Look for Hearthstone and click install:
[image]

It will ask for some other packages that need to be installed like mono or .net, just click you accept the installation.

When the process finishes you will be able to play Hearthstone

Comment: Hmm. I get stuck at an updating Blizzard agent step.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is how i installed it with Wine:**

Download the Battle.Net Client

Install Wine(i believe both 1.7 and 1.6 work)

(Just go to ubuntu software center, and type wine)

Run "Wine Configuration" from your application menu
Go to the tab "Libraries"

In "New override for library", enter "dbghelp" and click "Add..."

Then in "Existing overrides", select "dbghelp" and click "Edit..."

In the window that just popped up, select "Disable" and click on "Add".

Back in "New override for library", enter "msvcp100" and click "Add...".

Do not edit this entry in "Existing overrides"!

Click on "OK"

Install and start Battle.Net and Hearthstone as you would on a Windows machine

Information found here:http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/23fwzq/tutorial_how_to_play_hearthstone_on_linux_via_wine/

**Just note this:
You may or may not experiance minor glitches, since HS is not yet out for Linux**.

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS neither 1st or 2nd answer worked for me.
If you see Program Error like this:

[image]

you need to do the following:
1. There's something wrong with Ubuntu's Windows Fonts they need to be removed by typing this into the Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

2. Download the .deb to your Home folder from here: 
[Download ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download)
3. and install them from the Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

After doing this install Hearthstone again following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/624932/458673)